# What's this box under the hood of a 2007 Lexus ES350?

Tags: part-identification, lexus

[image: mystery box]

Does it contain anything that requires regular maintenance, like a filter?

What's a good online source of diagrams to identify car parts by location?

Comment: Looks like a resonator. It cuts down on the whooshing sound the intake can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the above answer that it looks very much like a intake resonator/dampener box.

Like he said it's designed to make the intake a little quieter but as often as not it's also there to even out and dampen the intake pulses.

Usually, they tend to be hollow but not having any experience on that particular car I can only surmise  it's purpose ans construction.Normally,they require no maintenance but again without first hand exp I wouldn't like to make any definitive claim about that.

What i can say is that from the image you've provided although the housing appears to be made in two halves it doesn't appear to have any kind of spring clips you can unlatch in order to seperate them which suggests it isn't intended to be opened up. It looks permanently bonded so unleas thee's any obvious way to open up the housing I'd say just leave it alone.

As for diagrams you can trawl the net..... one way is to enter your make, model, engine code, model year etc into google searching for specifically pdf files or doing an image search. Trouble is it's pretty hit and miss. You may find exactly the diagram you're looking for or one that's tantalisingly close but no use.

I've found signing up to sites like Scribd.com and doing a document search has netted me some excellent technical manuals, wiring diagrams etc.

Thing is free online documents of this type are sometimes there but often not. Another alternative is to join say a Lexus Owner's Club site where you may get what you're after

I don't have a Lexus but I do own a Toyota and have spent many, many hours searching the Internet technical and workshop manuals, wiring diagrams etc.

Like I said, joining the Toyotaownersclub was one route, opening an account on Scribd.com was another but I ended up buying an online manual from emanualsonline.com for £10. It was a very high quality and well worth the money.

Hope that helps